# Not able to select correct function from dropdown box in python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

I am using Python 3.6 and am not able to figure out the logic to select the correct def function when I select a choice from the dropdown box. Below is the code. Please help.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
#Combo box
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10)

tkvar = StringVar(root)
choices = {'gl_Auto','gl_Elec','gl_OP'}
tkvar.set('gl_Auto')

popupMenu = OptionMenu(frame, tkvar, *choices)
popupMenu.pack(side=LEFT,padx=20,pady=20)
Label(frame, text="Select_GL")

def Select_GL(*args):  # When I select different gl, it should go to that function
    print(tkvar.get())

# link function to change dropdown
tkvar.trace('w', Select_GL)

def keyword_auto():
    print(Automotive)

def keyword_elec():
    print(Electronics)

def keyword_OP():
    print(OP)

root=mainloop()
```

Comment: Basically, when I select a choice from the drop down box, it should go to that particular def function and it's not happening.so can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what does it do? "not happening" is rather vague. Have you tried examining the results of `str(tkvar.get())` to see if it's what you think it is? Also, you're using a variable named `gl_auto` but you don't seem to be setting it anywhere.

Comment: {str(tkvar.get())} it gives the output but I want it to select def function of that choice.

Comment: when I select gl_elec it throws error as Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kollurma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args

Comment: That error is telling you exactly what is wrong. Read it, and assume that it is telling you the truth. Pay particular attention to this part: `NameError: name 'gl_auto' is not defined`

Comment: it is throwing one more error as in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: Select_GL() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given what does this mean?  I new to python can you please explain if possible?

Comment: Fix the error with `gl_auto` and the other errors will go away.

Comment: I changed tkvar.set(gl-auto) to tkvar.set() and its throws error tkvar.set()
TypeError: set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Comment: can you please point me where gl_auto is not defined?so that I can work on it?

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what line. Line 17.

Comment: so I should remove gl_auto and place tkvar,set()?

Comment: Bryan I got that but want i want is that when I select gl_elec it should go to def keyword_elec().

Comment: I have changed that error with print(tkvar.get()) and its showing expected answer.but my requirement is when I select gl_elec it should call the def function keyword_elec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go to a function based on the variable value, you simply need to compare the value to an expected *string*, and call the appropriate function.

```
def Select_GL(*args):
    value = tkvar.get()
    if value == "gl_Auto":
        keyword_auto()
    elif value == 'gl_Elec':
        keyword_elec()
    else
        keyword_OP()
```